# Brand logo on navbar - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Is there a way to dynamically resize the nav-bar brand logo image to go over the nav-bar itself without it losing it's size?

I want it to be fixed on the top of the nav-bar and be over it. I don't want the nav-bar to adjust to the image.

[image: Image of webpage]

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #97CACA;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1% 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

.navbar-brand>img {
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0px;
}

.navbar-brand {
  float: left;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 0 0px;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a:focus,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .active a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #97CACA;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav li a {
  color: #E2F2E8;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="MyNavbar">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <img src="https://preview.ibb.co/cuc7sb/logo_sitters.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">A Nossa Missão</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Os Nossos Serviços</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contactos</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a position: absolute to your **.navbar-brand** and remove float: left
Added top: 0 and left: 0 to put it in place. You can change them accordingly.

```
.navbar-brand {
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 0 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

Additionally, you need to style your ul after that, because it will be behind your logo

(this is a rough solution)

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse ul {
  float: right;
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/d67y3Ltn/1/

Comment: But it still doesn't overstep the navbar. The navbar always adjust to the size os the image and I want it to remain smaller

Example: anannyforu.com